# Dynamically draw a graph with node changing color

Tags: python, networkx, draw

I want to draw the evolution of a graph where some nodes change color.

```
%matplotlib tk
import networkx as nx 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

G = nx.Graph() 
adj_list = {2: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],    
3: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],    
5: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]} 
for i, j in adj_list.items():
    for k in j:
        G.add_edge(i, k)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

val_map = {8: 'r', 9:'r'}
values = [val_map.get(node,'g') for node in G.nodes()]
nx.draw(G,pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_size = 1000, node_color=values, font_size=20) 
plt.draw()
```

This way I have all nodes green but node 8 and 9 that are red. Now I want to change the color of some green nodes to red, replotting the graph on the same window.

```
def grafo(i):
    val_map [i]='r'
    values = [val_map.get(node,'g') for node in G.nodes()]
    nx.draw(G,pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_size = 1000, node_color=values, font_size=20)
    plt.draw()

for i in range(5):
    grafo(i+2)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I was expecting to see the graph with node 2 red, then after 1 second, with node 3 red, etc. What happens instead is that nothing happens for 5 seconds, then it appears a graph with node 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 red.

Sorry for the long and maybe confused description...

Comment: I think you should replace `time.sleep(1)` with `plt.pause(1)`, this should update your graph as it draws I believe.